# Monodevelop - Application disapear on click (anywhere)

Tags: user-interface, gtk, hide, monodevelop

I have a simple GUI application which uses Gtk. When I run it to test, application appear, but when I click (anywhere) application hide. It is also not visible in application's bar.

[image: When I start/debug application:]
[image: After click:]

Comment: Marked icon means that application is still running in background -just for info ;)

Answer (score 0):

Window's "TypeHint" was set to "Splash". I set it back to "Dialog" and that solved all problems mentioned before.